# '<>' in SQL server not returns NULL value rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following table (`Table_1`) in SQL server:

[image: Table 1]

And has following values in table.

[image]

I am using following query to fetch records which does not have 'Thakker' as `LastName`.

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
  FROM [dbo].[Table_1] WHERE LastName <> 'Thakker'
```

But it's return me only third row. I am expecting that it should return me second & third rows.

Why it's not returning second row. ?

Comment: *Why it's not returning second row. ?* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT [id],
       [FirstName],
       [LastName],
  FROM [dbo].[Table_1] WHERE LastName <> 'Thakker' OR LastName IS NULL
```

As per your question *`<>` operator not returns NULL value rows*  because 
`<>` operator does comparison with the two values so for comparison there should be two values  but

`NULL` is not a value. It just a placeholder which shows that there is no value present. Even `NULL` is also not equal to `NULL`. That's why SQL has `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` for such scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Please add `ISNULL` checking for column `LastName` to include NULL values in the select.

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
FROM [dbo].[Table_1] 
WHERE ISNULL(LastName,'') <> 'Thakker'
```

OR using a `CASE`

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[LastName]
FROM [dbo].[Table_1] 
WHERE 1=CASE WHEN LastName='Thakker' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: Is there any other way that without checking ISNULL for every row's last name I can get also NULL value rows?

Comment: @JigneshThakker How about using a case statement, plz check the edited answer.

Comment: How does `ISNULL` work with indexes? I'd say that your first solution would prevent index usage...